# How to build a solution for mutliple target frameworks?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We have a class library currently targeting `.NET 4.6.2` which has some dependencies  (SDK classes) that are resolved via nuget.

All the SDK-Assemblies required by that class library are available for multiple target platforms (eg. `4.6.2`, `4.5.2` etc.).

We are using VSTS to both build the library and pack/push it to a private NuGet feed.

Now, we need our Class-Library to both target `.NET 4.5.2` as well as `.NET 4.6.2` because we have a project using this library targeting `.NET 4.5.2` (*and no, unfortunately upgrading its target is no option*)

**So the acutal question is**: Is there a way to build the solution for both multipe target-frameworks?

What I tried so far:

- researched a lot, but this problem doesn't seem to be all to common (or i just can't manage to google properly in that particular case)
- experimented with build variables, but this doesn't seem to cut it either

I also thought about some kind of script for parsing and manipulating all the `packages.config` and `*.csproj` files, but I guess this isn't best practice at all.

Comment: If the class library targets .Net Framework 4.5.2 then it can be used by both code targetting 4.5.2 as well as anything later (including 4.6.2) just target the earliest version you can get away with.

Comment: @phuzi strangely, this doesn't seem to be possible, since the system the library is developed for, requires at least 4.6.2 in some versions and exaclty 4.5.2 in others.

Comment: Think you missed the point. I could write an app targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2 and use a library targeting .Net Framework 4.0. So long as your class library is targeting 4.5.2 your app can target 4.5.2 or later

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll try that out and get back when I'm done.

Comment: @phuzi i went with your approach and it worked for me. Kind of emberrassing that i wasn't able to figure this out myself but hey, thats what this community is for right? If you provide your comment as an answer i'll gladly accept it, since that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to have an assembly/class library that can be used by projects targeting different versions of the .Net Framework.

If you have projects targeting 4.5.2 and 4.6.2 but you want to provide a common library then have your library target 4.5.2. .Net makes is essentially backwards compatible so you can always use a library targeting a lower version than the version the consuming library/project targets. *Technically you could target anything below that too including 3.5, but why would you.*

This also applies to .Net Core and .Net Standard too but the combinations quickly stack up. If the library targets .Net Standard 1.0 then it can be consumed by projects targeting any version of .Net Standard >= 1.0, any version of .Net Core >= 1.0 and any version of .Net Framework >= 4.5.2. Take a look at the [docs on .Net Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) for details.

For more details on .Net Standard check out [this blog post from Daniel Crabtree](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/303/understanding-net-standard-an-interface-not-an-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, yes, this seems to be possible, but I have never seen any documentation of it, nor have I tried that myself, yet. I only stumbled over an open source project that used it and was flashed that this was possible.

It is actually quite simple: You have to manually edit your `*.csproj` file as follows:

1. Convert the project to the new sdk style format as if you would port it to .NET Standard (the document root should be `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`)
2. Instead of `<TargetFramework>net452</Targetframework>`, simply write `<TargetFrameworks>net452;net462</TargetFrameworks>`

If you open the properties page of such a project in Visual Studio, you see the field for the target platform readonly, so there is no direct support for it (yet). As a result of the build process, you will get multiple subfolders of your specified build output path that contain the assemblies for all of your specified target platforms in separate directories.

Comment: great, do you know anything regarding the nuget-dependecies?

Comment: @nozzleman well, I guess is that msbuild will restore the nuget dependencies for each target platform separately. In addition, you can specify dependencies conditional to the target platform, so I don't see a conceptual problem, but before you nail me, I really haven't tried, yet